# How to add and migrate new column data in opensearch index from mysql database without re-creating index?

Tags: opensearch

we have added a new column to MySQL and completed the migration for that field. I want to add that field and data to my open-search index without affecting the current index, without re-creating the index, without losing data, or re-creating the index using restHighLevelClient/ElasticSearchOperation in a spring boot application. I am using open-search and I am facing this strange situation.

Would someone kindly explain how to solve this issue?